# What is the purpose of the following function

Tags: c

This is my task. I googling for find out reason behind this function but can not find out. My teacher tell me `what is the use of this function`.

My Question is:

> What is the purpose of the following function, assuming that the parameter `size` represents the size of the array `data` that's also passed as a parameter. Further assume that `size` is at least 2.

This is sample code he give me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void procArray( int data[], int size ) {
     int temp = data[0];
     int index;
     for( index = 0; index < size - 1; index++ )
     {
         data[index] = data[index + 1];
         data[size-1] = temp;
         
         printf("%d ", + data[index]);
         printf("%d ", + data[size-1]);
     }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[2];
    procArray(arr, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Every time i got random number in output like:

```
32767 -2102338448
```

Comment: The array is not initialized. So the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Let's look at it from the other side: What output do you expect? What variables do you print, what values do you expect them to hold? Why?

Comment: `arr` contains whatever was in that memory place before.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have task like `What is the purpose of the following function, assuming that the parameter size represents the size of the array data that's also passed as a parameter. Further assume that size is at least 2` and give a sample code. And tell me what is the use of this function

Comment: Was the `main` function part of your task?

Comment: If you fix the warnings your compiler should show you in `main` you should be able to see a very different result and understand what the function does. Using an array with more than 2 elements would help as well.

Comment: The program demonstrates the principle "Garbage in, garbage out"

Comment: Thanks all who try to solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routine `procArray` appears to be written with the intent that it “rotate” the array one position “left,” meaning to modify the array such that, upon return from the function:

- The last element (index `[size-1]`) contains the value the first element (index `[0]`) the first element had upon calling the function.
- Each other element (index `[i]` for some `i` other than `size-1`) contains the value the element to its “right” (index `[i+1]`) had upon calling the function.

However, if this was the purpose, the function was written incorrectly. The statement `data[size-1] = temp;` should be after the loop, not inside it.

Further, the `main` routine fails to demonstrate how the function behaves because it fails to put values into `arr`.

A corrected function with a useful demonstration is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void procArray(int data[], size_t size)
{
     int temp = data[0];

     for (size_t i = 0; i < size-1; ++i)
         data[i] = data[i+1];

     data[size-1] = temp;
}


int main(void)
{
    int arr[5] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    procArray(arr, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("arr[%d] = %d.\n", i, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs:

```
arr[0] = 11.
arr[1] = 12.
arr[2] = 13.
arr[3] = 14.
arr[4] = 10.
```

Comment: Thank for answer. This is exactly i want.

Answer (score -2):

It's because you array is not initialized.

In C, when you write `int arr[2]` your array is initialized with random value.

Your array doesn't have data in it, so the compiler doesn't know and set a random value.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is correct. The second one is wrong for static or global variables and poorly explained. And the third one if more or less wrong: the compiler doesn't set anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).